# Request a local URL from a UI test target running on device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

When I attempt to make a URL request (using `URLSession.shared.dataTask`) from a UI test, running on device, it fails if the URL is on the local network, with the following error:

```
HelloWorldUITests-Runner[20156:4946160] Task <7634F9E1-915D-400B-9B68-4A768D58A4DE>.<1> finished with error [-1003] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-72000, NSUnderlyingError=0x28224def0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1003 "(null)" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorNWPathKey=satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: utun5, ipv4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-72000, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=10}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <7634F9E1-915D-400B-9B68-4A768D58A4DE>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <7634F9E1-915D-400B-9B68-4A768D58A4DE>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://redacted.local/redacted, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://redacted.local/redacted, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=10}
```

It is worth noting that I can successfully make URL requests:

- to URLs on the external internet from the UI test target running on device
- to local URLs from the UI test target running on a simulator
- to local URLs from the app target running on device

However, in the last of these, the app presents the alert which says:

> "HelloWorld" would like to find and connect to devices on your local
> network.

...and it only works if I accept the alert. If I tap "Don't Allow" then it fails with the same error as above. This suggests to me that the test runner needs to somehow be granted the same permissions that the app gets when the user taps that alert.

I am using Xcode 14.0.1 and the device is running iOS 15.6.1.

**Does anyone know if there is a workaround for this issue?**

Comment: I noticed you are using `http`.  Note Apple requires `https` connection. To use `http`, you need to set the "NSAppTransportSecurity" 
 in your `Info.plist` to allow `http` connection to the server. Have you done that?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @workingdogsupportUkraine - yes I have done that and I see the same regardless of http or https.

Answer (score 0):

This is an iOS 14+ feature

> Apps that access your local network can collect information about nearby devices in order to determine which networks you join and when. This information could be used to create a profile of you. With iOS 14 and iPadOS 14, any app that wants to interact with devices on your network must ask for permission the first time it tries to browse your local network.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211870

So for UI Testing on device I guess you have to manually accept the authorization once, and then run your UI Tests

Answer (score 0):

As the workaround, here is what I'm using:

`let springboardapp = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")` You can find a list of bundle IDs for apple apps here: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/deployment/depece748c41/web

`springboardApp.activate()` to make sure that Springboard is visible

`lazy var myAppTestRunner = springboardapp.icons["MyAppUITests-Runner"].firstMatch`

`myAppTestRunner.tap()` activates your Test runner. You'll see just a black screen

And then you need to trigger the Local Network alert by the following:

`_ = ProcessInfo.processInfo.hostName`

Then just wait for alert to appear and tap OK button

`springboardapp.alerts.buttons["OK"].firstMatch` or `springboardapp.alerts.buttons["Allow"].firstMatch` for iOS16 and higher

Surely, you need to add a proper waiters and asserts here, but the idea in general should be clear.

If you need to get the same Local Network access alert in your main app, just add the same line `_ = ProcessInfo.processInfo.hostName` into the `AppDelegate`